# Change particular color in image including shades

Tags: swift, image-processing, uiimage

I would like to specifically change the `UIImage` color to any color (excluding the gray borders and lines and preserving the shading effect), using an extension method as shown below:

```
extension UIImage {
   func replaceFillColorTo(_ color: UIColor) {
      // what should I do in here?
   }
}
```

I would like the result to be as shown below:
[image]

The white shirt is the input and each colored shirt is the output using different colors.

Comment: Do you have control over the image generation? Are you using a vector program, so you could use SVG files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to do this is to generate your "template" image with transparency / alpha levels.

For example:

[image]

I used this image - had to do a little editing so it's *close* to your image...  (if you download it you can see the transparency matches the above):

[image]

Then we can change the background color of the imageView, and get these results:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

and this example code to produce the screen-caps above:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "vShirt")
        else { return }
        
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width)
        ])
        
        imgView.image = img
        
        imgView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .white,
            .systemGreen,
            .systemBlue,
            .systemPink,
            .yellow,
        ]
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        ])
        colors.forEach { c in
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = c
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            v.layer.borderWidth = 1
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(colorTap(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func colorTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = g.view else { return }
        imgView.backgroundColor = v.backgroundColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! Didn't think about it. Which vector program do you suggest?

Comment: @Didami - Lots of options out there, including programs such as Adobe Illustrator and CorelDraw ($$$). I'm not a graphic artist, so I can't suggest from that standpoint. I use [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com), and there is a free open-source application called [InkScape](https://inkscape.org) that I've heard people like. Of course, you don't **need** to use a vector-based program... based on **your** t-shirt image, I assumed that's what you were already using.

Comment: I use Sketch but I'm still learning, how can I draw the shadows (Black - 15% opacity zone)?

Comment: @Didami - set Fill to Black, then set the layer(s) to 15% Opacity. Here's a link to the file I played with: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jqmS7p5oLcBm5ZIUUvbJ1xXFtO5ksnW-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay I get it. Another question, How can I remove the white background by code? (I understand we use it to set the `imgView.backgroundColor`)

Comment: @Didami - *"remove the white background by code"* -- that will be much more difficult. That's why I asked in my initial comment if you have control over the image generation. Again, the most **straight-forward** way is to generate your image(s) with clear (opacity: 0%) and translucent (such as the black, opacity: 15%) areas that need to be "color changed."

Comment: @Didami -- If you can't make the "interior" portions clear, you *could* use direct image buffer manipulation to first flood-fill the bounding box with, say, blue... then change the alpha component of all white pixels to zero... then change the alpha component of all "gray range" pixels to 15... and then change the blue pixels back to white.

Answer (score 0):

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Swift")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.tintColor = .systemPink
```

You are not able to change the colour of a UIImage(). You are able to change the TINT.

Here is a resource for you to review.
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-change-uiimage-color-in-swift/

```
extension UIImage {

func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    let maskImage = cgImage!

    let width = size.width
    let height = size.height
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    context.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage)
    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.fill(bounds)

    if let cgImage = context.makeImage() {
        let coloredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return coloredImage
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

Perhaps this function will also help you.

Comment: The problem is that by changing the tint color of the image, the shading effect and gray borders get affected.

Comment: @Didami check my edit

Comment: I appreciate your alternatives, but the result is still not as expected.

Comment: @Didami, worth a shot! not sure if this functionality you are looking for is possible. My thought is to simply include more images with various colors and when a user changes the color you simply change the image